# deploy application without the .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I have to give my customer my application. It's a simple application(3Mo). 
I think it's really unnecessary to oblige my client to install the whole .NET framework (the 3.5) to work with a simple application (3 mo). I mean I'm sure that there is a way to avoid that, just include some dlls or something like that.
Well I have the dll in my project reference(LINQ dll, core Dll, system Dll, winfom Dll, office Dll and some other)
is it possible to give the application with those dll and that way I avoid installing the whole .NET framework?
Well I don't even need to make an MSI or setup project,
just give him the exe generated with Visual Studio and that's it.

I'm using VS 2010, C#, 3.5.NET

Comment: As I have recently answered a similar question: yes you can deploy the application to the client computer but if he doesn't have .NET framework installed this application simply won't run. That's how it is. If you don't like it use C++ or whatever.

Comment: a) Your client probably has the framework installed and b) if not, there's a lightweight profile you can use from about V3.5 (except it doesn't include Linq) and even the full framework is not exactly a huge install. Realistically there are far more important things to worry about

Comment: Using the client profile of framework should also help easily upgrade any machine if don't find the target framework there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If these conditions are true:**

a) you really want to avoid .NET framework dependency

b) it's a really easy/small application

```
Consider the option of porting it to c++
```

---

**If not**

```
use default framework (.NET 2, or 3.5 or 3.5SP1) that comes by default in windows as Dan Puzey said.
```

Comment: If he were going to port it to something else I would recommend Delphi. Yes, it is not dead yet and it would be much easier to move from.

Comment: I choose C++ for the answer because syntax is really similar (less work to do)

Comment: the syntax might be, but some concepts differ

Answer (score 3):

It's worth noting that Windows comes with various flavours of .Net installed depending on the version of Windows.  If I remember correctly...

- Win7 comes with .NET 3.5 SP1
- Vista comes with .NET 3.5
- XP SP2 includes .NET 2

Depending on your target audience you might find that this is good enough!

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible. Client has to install .NET Framework 3.5 (with SP1) redistributable package.

**Edit:** If you didn't want client dependency on .NET Framework you should choose another application type: Web application where .NET dependency is only on the server.

Comment: But why with the Sp1? why not the 3.5 only?

Comment: Because when you create application in VS2010 for .NET 3.5 it will use 3.5 SP1.

Answer (score 0):

Most people have some flavor of .NET installed although most don't yet have 3.5. But you can create an installer that will download an install transparently to the user.  Also if you target the Client Profile this dependency will be smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Your client should have .net, there's no reason not to and if they haven't, they are a fool. Running XP with less than Service Pack 2 is dangerous. For the non-technically-inclined, compare it to using a van that's been subject to a manufacturer's recall. It may not necessarily be faulty, but the manufacturer has told you that it's no longer fit for use and are willing to make good at their own expense. As a responsible business owner, you wouldn't shirk that responsibility. In a similar vein, maintaining your Windows installation to the manufacturer's recommendation is **not** optional.

Comment: They don't need to be fools, they can be _special_. Embedded Versions of Windows XP have various optional packages - event .NET is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered making it a web app, with asp.net? The effort of porting should be less than a complete rewrite (depends on the applications functionality).